# Is there a name of the rule that $ \lVert x + z \rVert^2 + \lVert x - z \rVert^2 = 2 \lVert x \rVert^2 + 2\lVert z \rVert^2 $?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm a bit new to real analysis. Today, I came across this particular equality, whcih seems obvious to me.
$$ \lVert x + z \rVert^2 + \lVert x - z \rVert^2 =  2 \lVert x \rVert^2 + 2\lVert z \rVert^2 $$
Is there a specific name for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the parallelogram law of norms induced by inner products.

Comment: Thank you so much!